# rapply error passing in a list, unable to read in passed argument

Tags: r, lapply

Here's a working example

When I run the following:

```
example <- list()
example[[1]] <-matrix(c(1000000,2000000,2000000,5000000), nrow=4, ncol = 1)
example[[2]] <-matrix(c(1500000,2200000,2200000,5000000, 3500000), nrow=5, ncol = 1)

custom_func=function(X, O_low, O_high, A_low, A_high){
  d_vec = vector(length = 1)
  D_occ = pmin(pmax(X-O_low,0),O_high)
  TOTAL_D = pmin(pmax(sum(D_occ)-A_low,0),A_high)
  d_vec[i]=TOTAL_D
  return(mean(d_vec, na.rm=TRUE))
}

rapply(example, custom_func(O_low=1000000, O_high=3000000, A_low=5000000, A_high=25000000), how='list')
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error in pmax(X - O_low, 0) : 
  argument "X" is missing, with no default
```

X should be a `example[[1]]` and then `example[[2]]`, but how do I actually pass that in? 
Eventually, O_low, O_high, A_low, A_high will all be looped values, and the size of example would vary.

If I did something like below, it seems to automatically detect what I need to pass in...
`rapply(example, mean, how='list')`

Comment: What is `i` in `d_vec[i]=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we remove the `[i]` in `d_vec[i]`, it should work if we either use anonymous function call (`function(x)`) or just specify the parameters and the function without using `()`

```
 custom_func=function(X, O_low, O_high, A_low, A_high){
     d_vec = vector(length = 1)
     D_occ = pmin(pmax(X-O_low,0),O_high)
     TOTAL_D = pmin(pmax(sum(D_occ)-A_low,0),A_high)
     d_vec =TOTAL_D
     return(mean(d_vec, na.rm=TRUE))
   }
```

Using anonymous function (lambda function)

```
rapply(example, function(x) custom_func(x, O_low=1000000, 
         O_high=3000000, A_low=5000000, A_high=25000000), how='list')
#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 3400000
```

Or without lambda call

```
rapply(example, custom_func, O_low=1000000, 
         O_high=3000000, A_low=5000000, A_high=25000000, how='list')
#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 3400000
```